# PHP - Associative array assign third key value from key one and key two values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, associative-array

I have an associative array that looks like this:

```
$sensorThreshold = [
  'ph' => [
    'minPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->min_threshold ?? 0,
    'maxPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->max_threshold ?? 0,
    'sum' =>  $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->min_threshold + $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->max_threshold,
  ]
]
```

How I can access the `minPh` and `maxPh` values when I'm defining the array? Like:

```
$sensorThreshold = [
  'ph' => [
    'minPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->min_threshold ?? 0,
    'maxPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->max_threshold ?? 0,
    'sum' =>  minPh + maxPh,
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can save it to the variable

```
$sensorThreshold = [
    'ph' => [
        'minPh' => $minPh = ($sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->min_threshold ?? 0),
        'maxPh' => $maxPh = ($sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->max_threshold ?? 0),
        'sum' => $minPh + $maxPh,
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first define the array as is:

```
$sensorThreshold = [
  'ph' => [
    'minPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->min_threshold ?? 0,
    'maxPh' => $sensorThreshold->where('name', 'Ph')->last()->max_threshold ?? 0,
  ]
]
```

and add the `sum` key afterwards:

```
$sensorThreshold['ph']['sum'] = $sensorThreshold['ph']['minPh'] + $sensorThreshold['ph']['maxPh'];
```